# ¿Como puedo imprimir desde php hacia una impresora Zebra?

Tags: php, php7, impresión, zebra

escribo para solicitarles su guía referente a lo siguiente :

Necesito imprimir desde php hacia una impresora Zebra ZT410.

Desconozco como hacerlo, si existe alguna librería o función que pueda usar, les agradeceré alguien pueda orientarme un poco.

Lo que necesito imprimir es tres registros de una base de datos con solo pulsar un boton :

VALOR 1
VALOR 2
VALOR 3
etc

Al pulsar botón me imprima todos los registros que encuentre de manera consecutiva en la impresora Zebra en etiquetas distintas.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Entiendes que PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el Servidor y no en el cliente? ¿Entiendes que por motivos de seguridad, ningún navegador te va a permitir imprimir sin la participación del usuario? Ante tu pregunta sólo me queda el siguiente escenario: tu impresora está instalada en el Servidor que ejecuta el código PHP, y la impresión se realiza (en el Servidor) a petición de un cliente. Si este fuera el caso, ¿qué has intentado? Saludos

Comment: ¿Tu impresora Zebra ZT410 tiene tarjeta de red, puedes acceder directamente a ella por ip?

Comment: @MauricioContreras buenas tardes. Si estoy escribiendo acá en el foro es para solicitar ayuda de buena manera, no para recibir el tipo de respuesta que acabas de escribir. ¿Entiendes? ...Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si puedes acceder a tu impresora directamente desde su ip, puedes abrir un socket de red y enviarle directamente el código zpl, un ejemplo de esto sería:

```
function printjob(){

    $zpl =""; 
    $zpl .= "^XA";
    //asigna ubicación
    $zpl .= "^FO100,100^BY3^BCN,100,Y,N,N";
    //configura el codigo de barras
    $zpl .= "^A0N,20^FO10,18^CI28^TBN,304,60";
    //asigna el valor del código
    $zpl .="^FD" . "123456" . "^FS";
    $zpl .="^XZ";

    try
    {
        //abrimos el soket de red a la ip de la impresora y el puerto por defecto de zebra es el 9100
        $printerIp ="192.168.1.10";
        $fp=pfsockopen($printerIp,9100);
        fputs($fp,$zpl);
        fclose($fp);

        echo 'Successfully Printed';
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

todas esta operación de impresión la realizará el servidor y solo debes administrar las peticiones de los clientes

Comment: Hola Abraham, te agradezco enormemente tu ayuda. Efectivamente le asigne una ip a la impresora y ya tengo comunicación y logro enviar tu ejemplo desde php. El unico problema es que la impresora imprime pero sale todo en blanco...la probé haciendo una prueba de windows y salen perfectas en negro las letras pero desde el codigo php sale todo en blanco...que será? Muchas gracias Abraham.

Comment: Era el código ZPL, lo cambie por otro que encontré super simple y funciona. Otra vez muchas gracias Abraham!!!!

Comment: @FernandoAguayo que bueno que funcionó, lo más seguro es que el ZPL de mi ejemplo estaba usando dimensiones fuera del tamaño de tu etiqueta y por eso salia en blanco. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo mi imprezora zebra no tiene Tarjeta de red ese es el detalle en mi caso alguien sabe como le puedo hacer con PHP

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/338665)

Answer (score -2):

ESTE ES EL CODIGO CON EL QUE OBTUBE RESULTADOS CON WINDOWS SERVER

CODIGO

```
<?php

    
$DocNum = $_REQUEST['DocNum'];
$CardName = $_REQUEST['CardName'];
$LicTradNum = $_REQUEST['LicTradNum'];
$Tel1 = $_REQUEST['Tel1'];
$Address2 = $_REQUEST['Address2'];
$f1 = $_REQUEST['f1'];
$f2 = $_REQUEST['f2'];
$f3 = $_REQUEST['f3'];
$f4 = $_REQUEST['f4'];
$f5 = $_REQUEST['f5'];
$f6 = $_REQUEST['f6'];
$f7 = $_REQUEST['f7'];
$f8 = $_REQUEST['f8'];
$m1a = $_REQUEST['m1a'];
$m1b = $_REQUEST['m1b'];
$m1c = $_REQUEST['m1c'];
$m1d = $_REQUEST['m1d'];
$m1e = $_REQUEST['m1e'];
$m2a = $_REQUEST['m2a'];
$m2b = $_REQUEST['m2b'];
$m2c = $_REQUEST['m2c'];
$m2d = $_REQUEST['m2d'];
$m2e = $_REQUEST['m2e'];
$m3a = $_REQUEST['m3a'];
$m3b = $_REQUEST['m3b'];
$m3c = $_REQUEST['m3c'];
$m3d = $_REQUEST['m3d'];
$m3e = $_REQUEST['m3e'];
$m4a = $_REQUEST['m4a'];
$m4b = $_REQUEST['m4b'];
$m4c = $_REQUEST['m4c'];
$m4d = $_REQUEST['m4d'];
$m4e = $_REQUEST['m4e'];
$m5a = $_REQUEST['m5a'];
$m5b = $_REQUEST['m5b'];
$m5c = $_REQUEST['m5c'];
$m5d = $_REQUEST['m5d'];
$m5e = $_REQUEST['m5e'];
$m6a = $_REQUEST['m6a'];
$m6b = $_REQUEST['m6b'];
$m6c = $_REQUEST['m6c'];
$m6d = $_REQUEST['m6d'];
$m6e = $_REQUEST['m6e'];
$m7a = $_REQUEST['m7a'];
$m7b = $_REQUEST['m7b'];
$m7c = $_REQUEST['m7c'];
$m7d = $_REQUEST['m7d'];
$m7e = $_REQUEST['m7e'];
$m8a = $_REQUEST['m8a'];
$m8b = $_REQUEST['m8b'];
$m8c = $_REQUEST['m8c'];
$m8d = $_REQUEST['m8d'];
$m8e = $_REQUEST['m8e'];
$m9a = $_REQUEST['m9a'];
$m9b = $_REQUEST['m9b'];
$m9c = $_REQUEST['m9c'];
$m9d = $_REQUEST['m9d'];
$m9e = $_REQUEST['m9e'];
$m10a = $_REQUEST['m10a'];
$m10b = $_REQUEST['m10b'];
$m10c = $_REQUEST['m10c'];
$m10d = $_REQUEST['m10d'];
$m10e = $_REQUEST['m10e'];
$cita = $_REQUEST['cita'];
$m11a = $_REQUEST['m11a'];  
$status = 'Activa';
    date_default_timezone_get('America/Guadalajara_city');
    $fecha_actual=date("y-m-d H:i:s");

    $conexion2 = new mysqli("localhost","root","INFO","INFO");

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO INFO VALUES (
    '0','$DocNum','$CardName','$LicTradNum','$Tel1','$Address2',
    '$f1','$f2','$f3','$f4','$f5','$f6','$f7','$f8',
    '$m1a','$m1b','$m1c','$m1d','$m1e',
    '$m2a','$m2b','$m2c','$m2d','$m2e',
    '$m3a','$m3b','$m3c','$m3d','$m3e',
    '$m4a','$m4b','$m4c','$m4d','$m4e',
    '$m5a','$m5b','$m5c','$m5d','$m5e',
    '$m6a','$m6b','$m6c','$m6d','$m6e',
    '$m7a','$m7b','$m7c','$m7d','$m7e',
    '$m8a','$m8b','$m8c','$m8d','$m8e',
    '$m9a','$m9b','$m9c','$m9d','$m9e',
    '$m10a','$m10b','$m10c','$m10d','$m10e',
    '$cita','$m11a','$fecha_actual','$status')";
    $resultado2 = $conexion2->query($query2);
    
$conexion1 = new mysqli("localhost","root","INFO","INFO");



                                $query1 = "SELECT *  FROM INFO order by id desc limit 1 ";
                                $resultado1 = $conexion1->query($query1);
                                while ($row = $resultado1->fetch_assoc()){
$domi = $row ['DocNum'];    
$aMostrar=substr($domi, 0, 6);
$addressa= $aMostrar; 

$dom = utf8_decode($row ['Address2']);  
$aMostrar1=substr($dom, 0, 75);
$domi1= $aMostrar1; 

$dom2 = utf8_decode($row ['Address2']); 
$aMostrar2=substr($dom2, 75, 150);
$domi2= $aMostrar2; 
$cliente = $row['CardName'];
$id = $row['id'];
$rfc = $row['LicTradNum'];
$tel = $row['Tel1'];
$ruta = $row ['cita'];
$fecha = $row ['fecha'];
$porcobrar = $row ['f1'];
$pagado = $row ['f2'];
$alregreso = $row ['f3'];
$aocurre =$row ['f7'];
$adomicilio = $row ['f4'];
$valor_declarado = $row ['f6'];
// valores de filas de producto / documentos 
$m1a = $row ['m1a'];
$m1b = $row ['m1b'];
$m1c = $row ['m1c'];
$m1d = $row ['m1d'];
$m1e = $row ['m1e'];

$m2a = $row ['m2a'];
$m2b = $row ['m2b'];
$m2c = $row ['m2c'];
$m2d = $row ['m2d'];
$m2e = $row ['m2e'];

$m3a = $row ['m3a'];
$m3b = $row ['m3b'];
$m3c = $row ['m3c'];
$m3d = $row ['m3d'];
$m3e = $row ['m3e'];

$m4a = $row ['m4a'];
$m4b = $row ['m4b'];
$m4c = $row ['m4c'];
$m4d = $row ['m4d'];
$m4e = $row ['m4e'];

$m5a = $row ['m5a'];
$m5b = $row ['m5b'];
$m5c = $row ['m5c'];
$m5d = $row ['m5d'];
$m5e = $row ['m5e'];

$m6a = $row ['m6a'];
$m6b = $row ['m6b'];
$m6c = $row ['m6c'];
$m6d = $row ['m6d'];
$m6e = $row ['m6e'];

$m7a = $row ['m7a'];
$m7b = $row ['m7b'];
$m7c = $row ['m7c'];
$m7d = $row ['m7d'];
$m7e = $row ['m7e'];

$m8a = $row ['m8a'];
$m8b = $row ['m8b'];
$m8c = $row ['m8c'];
$m8d = $row ['m8d'];
$m8e = $row ['m8e'];

$m9a = $row ['m9a'];
$m9b = $row ['m9b'];
$m9c = $row ['m9c'];
$m9d = $row ['m9d'];
$m9e = $row ['m9e'];

$m10a = $row ['m10a'];
$m10b = $row ['m10b'];
$m10c = $row ['m10c'];
$m10d = $row ['m10d'];
$m10e = $row ['m10e'];

$m11a = $row ['m11a'];


echo $addressa;
echo $cliente;

}

require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php'; //Nota: si renombraste la carpeta a algo diferente de "ticket" cambia el nombre en esta línea
use Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
/*echo '<script language="javascript">alert(" desea imprimir realmente  ");</script>
<script>';
*/

//cariable con codigo zpl de maquetado de etiqueta con variables concatenadas  pata imprimir la informacion de la pre guia 


$preguia1 = '
^XA


    ^FO20,155^GB770,0,4^FS
   ^FO680,155^GB0,100,4^FS
    ^FT250,176^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDORDEN DE SOLICITUD DE RECOLECCION^FS
    ^FO20,180^GB660,0,2^FS
     ^FT26,201^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDFOLIO :^FS
     ^FO100,180^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT105,201^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD'.$addressa.'^FS
    ^FO240,180^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT245,201^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD  PRE GUIA :^FS
    ^FO350,180^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT355,201^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD'.$id.'^FS
    ^FO470,180^GB0,50,2^FS
    ^FO20,205^GB450,0,2^FS
    ^FT26,226^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDFECHA DE ENVIO :^FS
    ^FO180,205^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT184,226^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD '.$id.' ^FS
    ^FO300,205^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT304,226^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD RUTA ^FS
    ^FO20,230^GB660,0,2^FS
   ^FO693,153
   ^BQN,2,3
   ^FD       PRE GUIA  ' .$id.'^FS
   ^FT475,223^A0N,45,22^FH\^FD'.$ruta.'^FS
   ^FO20,255^GB770,0,4^FS
   ^FO20,230
   ^GB660,25,25,,0^FS
   ^FO360,235^CF0,22,22
   ^FR^FDREMITENTE^FS
   ^FT35,277^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDINFO ^FS
   ^FO270,255^GB0,25,2^FS
   ^FT290,277^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDRFC : ^FS
   ^FO350,255^GB0,25,2^FS
   ^FT370,277^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDINFO^FS
   ^FO520,255^GB0,25,2^FS
   ^FT540,277^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDTELEFONOS: ^FS
   ^FO660,255^GB0,25,2^FS
   ^FT680,277^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDINFO^FS
   ^FO20,280^GB770,0,2^FS
   ^FT24,302^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDDOMICILIO: ^FS
   ^FO130,280^GB0,25,2^FS
   ^FT144,302^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDINFO^FS
   ^FO470,280^GB0,25,2^FS
   ^FT484,302^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDCOLONIA Y C.P.^FS
   ^FO630,280^GB0,25,2^FS
   ^FT644,302^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDINFO ^FS
   ^FO20,315^GB770,0,2^FS
   ^FO20,305
   ^GB770,35,35,,0^FS
   ^FO340,315^CF0,26,26
   ^FR^FDDESTINATARIO^FS
   ^FT26,370^A0N,25,25^FH\^FD'.$cliente.'^FS
   
   ^FO20,380^GB770,0,2^FS
   ^FT54,402^A0N,20,24^FH\^FDRFC:^FS
   ^FT160,402^A0N,20,24^FH\^FD'.$rfc.'^FS
   ^FT400,402^A0N,20,24^FH\^FDTELEFONOS:^FS
   ^FT600,402^A0N,20,24^FH\^FD'.$tel.'^FS
   ^FO20,405^GB770,0,2^FS
   ^FT360,427^A0N,20,24^FH\^FDDOMICILIO:^FS
   ^FO20,430^GB770,0,2^FS
   ^FT26,460^A0N,25,20^FH\^FD'.$domi1.'^FS

   ^FO20,470^GB770,0,2^FS
^FT26,500^A0N,25,20^FH\^FD'.$domi2.'^FS
^FO20,510^GB770,0,2^FS

   ^FO20,510
   ^GB770,35,35,,0^FS
   ^FO170,518^CF0,26,26
   ^FR^FDFORMA DE PAGO, ENTREGA Y ASEGURANZA^FS
    ^FT34,566^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDMODALIDA DE ENVIO: ^FS
    ^FO220,545^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT238,566^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDPOR COBRAR ^FS
    ^FO365,545^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT378,566^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD'.$porcobrar.'^FS
    ^FO395,545^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT413,566^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDPAGADO ^FS
    ^FO500,545^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT510,566^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD'.$pagado.'^FS
    ^FO530,545^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT556,566^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDCOBRAR AL REGRESO ^FS
    ^FO760,545^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT770,566^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD'.$alregreso.'^FS
    ^FO20,570^GB770,0,2^FS
    ^FT28,591^A0N,20,17^FH\^FDSERVICIO OCURRE^FS
    ^FO160,570^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT165,591^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD'.$aocurre.'^FS
    ^FO180,570^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT185,591^A0N,20,17^FH\^FDENTREGA A DOMICILIO^FS
    ^FO350,570^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT357,591^A0N,20,20^FH\^FD'.$adomicilio.'^FS
    ^FO375,570^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FT381,591^A0N,20,20^FH\^FDVALOR DECLARADO :  ^FS
    ^FO20,595^GB770,0,2^FS

^FO20,595
   ^GB770,35,35,,0^FS
   ^FO250,603^CF0,26,28
   ^FR^FDDESCRIPCION DE MERCANCIA^FS
   ^FT57,655^A0N,20,18^FH\^FD BULTOS^FS
   ^FT140,655^A0N,20,28^FH\^FD DESCRIPCION^FS
   ^FT325,655^A0N,20,28^FH\^FD CONTENIDO^FS
   ^FT495,655^A0N,20,28^FH\^FD PEDIDO^FS
   ^FT645,655^A0N,20,28^FH\^FDENTREGA^FS
   ^FO20,660^GB770,0,4^FS

^FT27,685^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 1^FS
^FT55,685^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  '.$m1a.'^FS
^FT140,685^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m1b.'^FS
^FT325,685^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD'.$m1c.'^FS
^FT505,685^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m1d.'^FS
^FT645,685^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m1e.'^FS


^FO20,690^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,715^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 2^FS
^FT55,715^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m2a.'^FS
^FT140,715^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD'.$m2b.'^FS
^FT325,715^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD'.$m2c.'^FS
^FT505,715^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m2d.'^FS
^FT645,715^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m2e.'^FS

^FO20,720^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,745^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 3^FS
^FT55,745^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m3a.'^FS
^FT140,745^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m3b.'^FS
^FT325,745^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m3c.'^FS
^FT505,745^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m3d.'^FS
^FT645,745^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m3e.'^FS

^FO20,750^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,775^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 4^FS
^FT55,775^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m4a.'^FS
^FT140,775^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m4b.'^FS
^FT325,775^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m4c.'^FS
^FT505,775^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m4d.'^FS
^FT645,775^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m4e.'^FS

^FO20,780^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,805^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 5^FS
^FT55,805^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m5a.'^FS
^FT140,805^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m5b.'^FS
^FT325,805^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m5c.'^FS
^FT505,805^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m5d.'^FS
^FT645,805^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m5e.'^FS

^FO20,810^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,835^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 6^FS
^FT55,835^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m6a.'^FS
^FT140,835^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m6b.'^FS
^FT325,835^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m6c.'^FS
^FT505,835^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m6d.'^FS
^FT645,835^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m6e.'^FS

^FO20,840^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,865^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 7^FS
^FT55,865^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m7a.'^FS
^FT140,865^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m7b.'^FS
^FT325,865^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m7c.'^FS
^FT505,865^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m7d.'^FS
^FT645,865^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m7e.'^FS



^FO20,870^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,895^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 8^FS
^FT55,895^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m8a.'^FS
^FT140,895^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m8b.'^FS
^FT325,895^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m8c.'^FS
^FT505,895^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m8d.'^FS
^FT645,895^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m8e.'^FS



^FO20,900^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,925^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD 9^FS
^FT55,925^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m9a.'^FS
^FT140,925^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m9b.'^FS
^FT325,925^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m9c.'^FS
^FT505,925^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m9d.'^FS
^FT645,925^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m9e.'^FS



^FO20,930^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,955^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD10^FS
^FT55,955^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m10a.'^FS
^FT140,955^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m10b.'^FS
^FT325,955^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD '.$m10c.'^FS
^FT505,955^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD'.$m10d.'^FS
^FT645,955^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD'.$m10e.'^FS



^FO20,960^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,985^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD11^FS
^FT55,985^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD ^FS
^FT140,985^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD ^FS
^FT325,985^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD ^FS
^FT505,985^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT645,985^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD  ^FS



^FO20,990^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,1015^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD12^FS
^FT55,1015^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT140,1015^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT325,1015^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT505,1015^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT645,1015^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD  ^FS




^FO20,1020^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,1045^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD13^FS
^FT55,1045^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT140,1045^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT325,1045^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT505,1045^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT645,1045^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD  ^FS



^FO20,1050^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,1075^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD14^FS
^FT55,1075^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT140,1075^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT325,1075^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT505,1075^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT645,1075^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD  ^FS




^FO20,1080^GB770,0,4^FS
^FT27,1105^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD15^FS
^FT55,1105^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT140,1105^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT325,1105^A0N,20,22^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT505,1105^A0N,20,34^FH\^FD  ^FS
^FT645,1105^A0N,20,38^FH\^FD  ^FS




^FO20,1110^GB770,0,4^FS



   ^FO50,630^GB0,480,4^FS
  ^FO130,630^GB0,480,4^FS
  ^FO320,630^GB0,480,4^FS
  ^FO480,630^GB0,480,4^FS
  ^FO610,630^GB0,480,4^FS

    ^FT28,1145^A0N,26,18^FH\^FD COMENTARIOS : '.$m11a.'^FS
    ^FO20,1155^GB774,0,4^FS
    ^FO280,1180^GB300,0,4^FS
    ^FT340,1205^A0N,20,18^FH\^FD FIRMA DE RECIBIDO :^FS

    ^FO100,180^GB0,25,2^FS
    ^FO790,155^GB0,1000,4^FS
   ^FO20,155^GB0,1000,4^FS



^XZ
'; 

//}
/*
Este ejemplo imprime un hola mundo en una impresora de tickets
en Windows.
La impresora debe estar instalada como genérica y debe estar
compartida
 */

/*
Conectamos con la impresora
 */

/*
Aquí, en lugar de "POS-58" (que es el nombre de mi impresora)
escribe el nombre de la tuya. Recuerda que debes compartirla
desde el panel de control
 */

//$nombre_impresora = "talento1";
$nombre_impresora = "preguias2";

$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector($nombre_impresora);
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);

//$logo = EscposImage::load("logo.jpg", false);
//$printer->bitImage($logo);

/*
Imprimimos un mensaje. Podemos usar
el salto de línea o llamar muchas
veces a $printer->text()
 */
$printer->setTextSize(2, 2);
//$printer->text("Ticket con PHP");

$printer->setTextSize(2, 1);
//$printer->feed();
$printer->text($preguia);
$printer->text($preguia1); //pagina 2 por codifo zpl 
/*
Hacemos que el papel salga. Es como
dejar muchos saltos de línea sin escribir nada
 */
$printer->feed(15);

/*
Cortamos el papel. Si nuestra impresora
no tiene soporte para ello, no generará
ningún error
 */
$printer->cut();

/*
Por medio de la impresora mandamos un pulso.
Esto es útil cuando la tenemos conectada
por ejemplo a un cajón
 */
$printer->pulse();

/*
Para imprimir realmente, tenemos que "cerrar"
la conexión con la impresora. Recuerda incluir esto al final de todos los archivos
 */
$printer->close();
/*echo '<script language="javascript">alert(" imprecion completada ");</script>
<script>
function redireccionarPagina() {
  window.location = "HTTP://192.168.101.209:215";
}
setTimeout("redireccionarPagina()", 5000);
</script>
';*/


if($resultado1 == true) {

echo '<script language="javascript">alert("! PRE GUA IMPRESA CORRECTAMENTE!");</script>
<script>

function redireccionarPagina() {
  window.location = "javascript: history.go(-1);";
}
setTimeout("redireccionarPagina()", 3000);
</script>
';

} else {

echo '<script language="javascript">alert("! no se ha podido actualizar !");</script>
<script>';
}
?>
```

LIBRERIA Mike42

Comment: Podrías comentar sobre lo que realiza el código que compartes, de esta forma cuando alguien revisa tu respuesta sepa de que trata

Comment: Si no explicas que parte de esta pared de codigo soluciona el problema, tu respuesta no sirve de mucho. por favor mira [answer]